# C++: assign a integer to an integer pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I try to point `my_next` pointer to an integer value like below:

```
int my_function(int x) {
    return x+1;
}

int *my_next = &my_function(5);
```

but got the following error:

```
error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int'
```

Any idea what I did wrong and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: So how do I assign my_function output to *my_next? Thanks!

Comment: You don't. You've run into a **design** problem, and you're asking for a **code** solution. You need to explain **what** that pointer is used for, and why it needs to point at the value that the function returns.